# Как в C# правильно сравнивать строки

Tags: c#, c#-faq

Как в C# правильно сравнивать строки: `Equals` или `==`?

```
string str1 = "s";
string str2 = "s";

Console.WriteLine("eq: " + str1.Equals(str2));
Console.WriteLine("==: " + (str1 == str2));
```

В обоих случаях результат `True`, хотя [String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) является классом и оператор `==` должен был сравнить ссылки.

`IlDasm` показал, что создаются 2 переменные и сравниваются согласно методам `Equals` и `== (op_Equality)`

```
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "s"
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldstr      "s"
  IL_000c:  stloc.1
  IL_000d:  ldstr      "eq: "
  IL_0012:  ldloc.0
  IL_0013:  ldloc.1
  IL_0014:  callvirt   instance bool [mscorlib]System.String::Equals(string)
  IL_0019:  box        [mscorlib]System.Boolean
  IL_001e:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(object, object)
  IL_0023:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0028:  nop
  IL_0029:  ldstr      "==: "
  IL_002e:  ldloc.0
  IL_002f:  ldloc.1
  IL_0030:  call       bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Equality(string, string)
  IL_0035:  box        [mscorlib]System.Boolean
  IL_003a:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(object, object)
```

Comment: Оператор `==` сравнивает лишь ссылки (и тем самым j,sxyj бесполезен) лишь в Java. В C#, в отличие от Java, есть перегрузка операторов.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

В C# правильно сравнивать строки и через `==`, и через `Equals`. Но более предпочтительным будет сравнивать через `==`.

**Почему так?**

**Метод `Equals`** подразумевает сравнение **значений** объектов ссылочного типа, он объявлен как `virtual` и для строк он перегружен и сравнивает их, как и предполагается, по значению. В Ваших классах Вы должны давать свою реализацию для него. Иначе он будет вести себя как `ReferenceEquals` и для ссылок, которые указывают не на один объект будет давать `false`, хоть они и будут равны по значению.

**Оператор `==`** для строк представляют свою реализацию, отличную от стандартной для всех других объектов ссылочного типа. Если сравниваемые ссылки имеют тип `System.String`, то он сначала сравнит указывают ли ссылки на один тот же объект и если нет, то будет сравнивать две ссылки типа `System.String` по значению.

**Но маленькое замечание**, если мы сравниваем объект типа `System.String` (`string`) с объектом типа `System.Object` (object), который указывает на строку, они будут сравниваться по значениям.

Пример:

```
string str = "str";
object obj = "str";
bool result = str.Equals(obj);
```

`result` будет равен `true`, так как `obj` приведётся к типу `string`, потому что метод `Equals` мы вызвали у строки (объекта типа `string`).

Но если мы сравниваем объект типа `System.Object` (object), который указывает на строку, с объектом типа `System.String` (`string`) они будут сравниваться по ссылке.

Пример:

```
string str = "str";
object obj = "str";
bool result = obj.Equals(str);
```

`result` будет равен `false`, так как `str` приведётся к типу `object`, потому что метод `Equals` мы вызвали у объекта типа `object`.

Поэтому в данном случае важно привести `object` к типу `string`

Answer (score 6):

Оператор `==` не обязан сравнивать только ссылки. В C# операторы можно переопределять, и он, естественно, переопределен для множества типов.

Сравнение ссылок - это просто поведение по умолчанию для типов, для которых оператор `==` не переопределен.

Для типов, для которых переопределен оператор `==`, скорее всего будет переопределен и `Equals`, причем результат для обоих способов сравнения скорее всего будет совпадать (если не будет - значит при проектировании типа его автор просто ошибся).

Вот реализация `==` для String из [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,661):

```
public static bool operator == (String a, String b) {
   return String.Equals(a, b);
}

public static bool Equals(String a, String b) {
    if ((Object)a==(Object)b) {
        return true;
    }

    if ((Object)a==null || (Object)b==null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (a.Length != b.Length)
        return false;

    return EqualsHelper(a, b);
}
```

А вот реализация нестатического Equals оттуда же:

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == null)                        //this is necessary to guard against reverse-pinvokes and
        throw new NullReferenceException();  //other callers who do not use the callvirt instruction

    String str = obj as String;
    if (str == null)
        return false;

    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        return true;

    if (this.Length != str.Length)
        return false;

    return EqualsHelper(this, str);
}
```

Они отличаются только небольшой поправкой на нестатичность. Обе сравнивают ссылки и проверяют случай `null != null`, потом сравнивают длину на неравенство, и только потом - значение.

Answer (score 5):

В C# для строк перегружен и оператор == и метод Equals, так как строки чаще требуется сравнивать по значению, нежели по ссылкам. В случае с оператором == сначала происходит сравнение указателей строк, и если они равны, то метод возвращает true. В противном случае проверяется равенство операндов null (если хотя бы один из них равен null, возвращается false). Затем сравниваются длины строк. А затем происходит посимвольное сравнение строк (то есть сравнение по значению). Это делается с использованием указателей в неуправляемом коде (очевидно из соображений производительности), а также применяется размотка циклов (очевидно из тех же соображений, но это уже малоинтересные в данном случае детали). Если интересны детали, посмотреть можете [здесь](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c)