# Пропускает в цикле while условие в if и сразу переходит к else

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, sql-server, ftp, таймер

Я начинающий разработчик-самоучка. Я разрабатываю телеграмм-бота, который будет присылать уведомление пользователям при изменении даты у файла с FTP сервера.Вместе с уведомлением у меня происходит обновление базы данных. Моя проблема заключается в том, что когда я обновляю данные о файле на FTP сервере, то до перезапуска консоли моё значение не передаётся в базу данных. Таймер должен перезапускать ту часть кода, что отвечает за сравнение файла из бд с файла с FTP.

Вот код:

```
  private static async Task DataBaseInsertFtp(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update)
    {
        string path = "";
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string connection = reader.ReadLine();
            string login = reader.ReadLine();
            string password = reader.ReadLine();
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(connection);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("Последнее время обновления: {0}", response.LastModified);
            const double interval = 0.1 * 60 * 1000;
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
            timer.Interval = interval;
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                    string connectionString = @"";
                    string sqlExpressionSelect = $"SELECT * FROM DateFileFTP";
                using (SqlConnection connectionFTP = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    await connectionFTP.OpenAsync();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpressionSelect, connectionFTP);
                    SqlDataReader readerFTP = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                    {
                        while (await readerFTP.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            DateTime DateFile = Convert.ToDateTime(readerFTP["DateFile"]);
                            string sqlExpressionUpdate = $"UPDATE DateFileFTP SET DateFile = ('{response.LastModified}')";
                            if (DateFile != response.LastModified)
                            {
                                SqlCommand commandUpdate = new SqlCommand(sqlExpressionUpdate, connectionFTP);
                                commandUpdate.CommandText = sqlExpressionUpdate;
                                int number = await commandUpdate.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                                await Database.DataBaseOutput(botClient, update);
                                Console.WriteLine($"Обновлено объектов: {number}");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            Console.WriteLine("Обновление не произошло");
                            }
    
                        }
                    }
    
                }       
            };               
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Настолько низкая задержка в таймере была сделана лишь для тестирования, в проде задержка будет составлять примерно 5-10 минут.

Comment: А почему оно должно проваливаться в условие? Сравнивать в `if` следует только одинаковые типы данных. Смотрите что у вас в переменных. Проверяйте почему они не совпадают. Может вы вообще сравниваете не так.

Comment: Проблема заключается не в разных типах данных, поскольку когда проект компилируется, запрос UPDATE выполняется, и в базе данных меняются значения, но если во время работы программы закинуть обновлённый файл, то запрос UPDATE не выполняется и он просто уходит в else

Comment: А вы попробуйте вывести в консоль что у вас в `DateFile` и в `response.LastModified` перед `if`. Тогда будет что вообще обсуждать. Логируйте всю инфу по максимуму. Может у вас там только дата без времени, например. Всяко может быть.

Comment: @DarkCatTrue а вы вообще в курсе [как нужно сравнивать строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621921/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)?

Comment: @CrazyElf DateFile и response.LastModified имеют одно и то же значение

Comment: @DarkCatTrue Ну вот и надо разбираться, почему так. И какое именно значение? То есть код то правильно работает, что-то не то у вас с логикой, заложенной в код.

Comment: @CrazyElf у обоих переменных значение DateTime, показывает и время и дату с точностью до секунд. Проблема то и в том, что если файлик поменялся, а потом запустилась консоль, то бот отправит уведомление, но если отправить повторно во время того как консоль уже работает, то он не увидит изменений на FTP сервере.

Comment: Так. А коммит вы делать не забываете? Или может у вас автокоммит включен?

Comment: @CrazyElf Вы наверное будете сильно недовольны мной, если узнаете, что я ещё ни разу не пользовался гитом. Ну так или иначе я думаю ещё не поздно начать, а контроль версий я осуществляю пока локально.

Comment: @DarkCatTrue )))  Нет, это не про Git, это про БД. Хотя, кажется, для sql server коммитить не нужно. Странно это всё.

Comment: @CrazyElf Ну простите я ещё просто не очень опытный в этих делах, я вообще предполагаю, что у меня закрывается соединение в readerFTP или вообще он его пропускает каким-то образом. Я думаю, что причина именно в readerFTP заключается.

Comment: Ну пройдитесь отладчиком, либо нафигачьте там везде `Console.Writeline`, чтобы понимать, какие строки кода исполнялись, а какие нет. Кстати, у вас таймер - это локальная переменная. Я вообще не уверен, что он не будет утилизирован по выходе из этой функции. Может он вообще не будет запускаться. Кроме того, `timer.Enabled = true;` нужно делать только когда остальные параметры таймера уже выставлены. А то получится, что таймер запустится - а функция, которую нужно выполнять, ещё не задана. Ничего не произойдёт.

Comment: @CrazyElf Но у меня то он фактически вызывает else каждый указанный промежуток времени, по тому как указано в коде, проблема в том, что скипается if

Comment: Информация о файле считывается однократно перед запуском таймера. Перенесите код получения инфы о фале внутрь функции таймера и будет вам щастье. Ну а код немного пугает. Следите за обьектами классы которых реализуют dispose